# When is it a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

> Find all positive integer $k$ such that $k^k+1$ is a prime.

I only found $k=1,2,4$ where the values are $2,5,257$.

But I cannot prove why others will not work. Pls help tks.

PS: It is one of my exam qns which it ask for $k^k+1$ is prime less than $10^{20}$

Comment: Should have been asked here already. The next possible prime of this form is a huge fermat number, to be exact $F_{70}$. This number is far too large for a primality test , so in the case there is another prime of this form (which is very unlikely), we will never be able to show it.

Comment: How about K=6 ,10,...?

Comment: @BrightStar We can factor the expression $x^n + 1$ for any odd $n$. And by extension for any $n$ that's not a power of $2$. In your case we get
$$
6^6 + 1 = 36^3 + 1 = (36+1)(36^2-36+1)
$$
for $k = 6$, and similar for $k = 10$.

Comment: @BrightStar i check with my python code until 10^200 no other primes except k=1,2,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $k$ must be the form $k=2^{2^m},m\in \mathbb{N}$. If you want to find all primes being the form $k^k+1$ less than $10^{20}$, then
$$2^{2^m\cdot2^{2^m}}+1 \leq 10^{20}$$
Hence,
$$2^{2^{2^m+m}}\leq 10^{20}$$
$$2^m+m\leq \log_2\log_2(10^{20})<7$$
Finally, we can try $m=0,1,2$ corresponding to $k=2,4,16$. When $k=2,4$,$k^k+1$ is a prime. When $k=16$, note that this is a Fermat number $F_6$ which is not a prime.

Comment: Could you pls explain why must k be the form of $2^2^m$? Thank you

Comment: @SABKX $k$ must be a power of 2 which is explained by Arthur. Actually, $k$ must be  a power of a power of 2. If not, $k^k=(2^k)^n$, where $n$ has a odd prime factor. This will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @SABKX $k$ must be a power of $2$, because otherwise the exponent in $k^k$ has an odd factor and may be rewritten as $x^y$ with $y>1$ odd, and $x^y+1$ may be factored. Since $k = 2^n$ is a power of $2$, we must also have that $n$ is a power of $2$, otherwise $k^k = (2^n)^{2^n} = 2^{n\cdot 2^n}$ has an odd factor in its exponent, and $k^k+1$ may therefore be factored.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I forgot about the factorisation of x^odd. Thank you for the help.